# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a code to divide two polynomials given in binary form (newdata and proofin, respectively). When I run the code, however, I get:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np


def transformation_for_numpy_of_o():
    newdata = ("101001")
    freshdata = list(newdata)
    freshdatapoly = []

    for n in freshdata:
        if n == 1:
            freshdatapoly.append(1.0)
        if n == 0:
            freshdatapoly.append(0.0)

    freshdatapoly = np.array(freshdatapoly)

    return freshdatapoly


def transformation_for_numpy_of_proof():
    proofin = ("101001")
    proofing = list(proofin)
    proofpoly = []

    for n in proofing:
        if n == 1:
            proofpoly.append(1.0)
        if n == 0:
            proofpoly.append(0.0)

    proofpoly = np.array(proofpoly)

    return proofpoly


def total():
    # Based on http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.polydiv.html

    o_transformed = transformation_for_numpy_of_o()
    proof_transformed = transformation_for_numpy_of_proof()

    numer = np.array(o_transformed)
    denomin = np.array(proof_transformed)
    answer = np.polydiv(numer, denomin)

    print (answer)

total()
```

I am new to numpy and don't understand this error. How can I fix this?

---

*EDIT: Entire Traceback, as requested:

```
/Users/M/anaconda/envs/Invictus/bin/python/Users/Max/PycharmProjects/1/Origin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/M/PycharmProjects/1/Origin", line 49, in <module>
    total()
  File "/Users/M/PycharmProjects/1/Origin", line 46, in total
    answer = np.polydiv(numer, denomin)
  File "/Users/M/anaconda/envs/Invictus/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 895, in polydiv
    w = u[0] + v[0]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post the entire traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing ints and string so your if's never evaluate to True therefore `proofpoly` is always empty when you `np.array(proofpoly)` the same applies to  `freshdatapoly`:

Change  freshdata  and proofing:

```
 freshdata = map(int,"101001")
 proofing = list(map(int,"101001"))
```

Since you create them just make each a list of ints:

```
import numpy as np


def transformation_for_numpy_of_o():
    freshdata = [1,0,1,0,0,1]
    freshdatapoly = []
    for n in freshdata:
        if n == 1:
            freshdatapoly.append(1.0)
        if n == 0:
            freshdatapoly.append(0.0)
    return np.array(freshdatapoly)


def transformation_for_numpy_of_proof():
    proofing = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    proofpoly = []
    for n in proofing:
        if n == 1:
            proofpoly.append(1.0)
        if n == 0:
            proofpoly.append(0.0)
    return np.array(proofpoly)
```

Now when you run it you get a result:

```
In [2]: total()
(array([ 1.]), array([ 0.]))
```

Maybe there is more we cannot see but currently the code is equivalent to:

```
def transformation_for_numpy_of_o():
    freshdata = [1,0,1,0,0,1]
    return np.array(freshdata)

def transformation_for_numpy_of_proof():
    proofing = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    return np.array(proofing)
```

If there are other possible values you can still use a list comp:

```
def transformation_for_numpy_of_proof():
    proofing = [1, 0, 4,5,1, 0, 0, 1, 4,3,5]
    return np.array([i for i in proofing if i in {1,0}])
```